# Find and replace the word in the given sentence using bash unix

Tags: unix

Am trying to replace a word in the given sentence
for example :

var=number 1, number 2

In the above variable "**var**" I want to replace "," with " **\',\'** ".
I have tried but since "\" is escaping character I am unable to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sed like:

```
 echo "var=number 1, number 2" | sed "s/,/\',\'/"
```

Output:

```
sh-4.3$ echo "var = hello, world" | sed "s/,/\',\'/"                                   
var = hello',' world
```

If you need "\" before comma, then use it like:

```
sh-4.3$ echo "var = hello, world" | sed "s/,/\\\',\\\'/"                           
var = hello\',\' world
```